# Is glob() the best way to get specific files with specific string, or extension?

Tags: php, glob

**Is the method correct?**

3 different data types:

- with 'txt' extension (* .txt)
- contain '_th' in the name extension 'jpg' (* _th.jpg)
- only files without extension 'txt' and in name '_th'

```php
  $dir = "./content/media/artworks";

  // ignore jpg-pictures if the name '_th' appears. And files with 'txt' extension.
  $imgs = glob($dir.'/*{[!_th].jpg,*.[!txt]}', GLOB_BRACE);

  // Just take jpg images with the name '_th'
  $thumbs = glob($dir.'/*?_th.*');

  // Just take files with 'txt' extensions
  $txts = glob($dir.'/*?.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern for glob is wrong. This here * [!_th]. Jpg does not mean that before .jpg is not a "_th". 
It means that the last character before the point not be permitted '_', no 't' and no 'h'.

Use array_diff() to get all jpg-files which not contain thumbs.

```
$thumbs = glob($dir.'/*_th.jpg');

$jpgWithoutThumbs = array_diff(glob($dir.'/*.jpg'), $thumbs);
```